# Programattically changing the Owner of a Case object

Tags: soap-api, c#

I am working on a front-end for our Support staff to simplify managing of SalesForce cases. I am trying to implement a "take ownership" button, where a user can assign a case to themselves out of a SalesForce queue.

I am 99% of the way there, but the update() call fails with the following error:

```
INVALID_TYPE: Must send a concrete entity type.
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void AssignTo(this SFDC.Case sfcase, string NewOwner)
{
  var sf = sfSoap.getInstance();
  var owner = sfcase.Owner;

  try
  {
    var q1 = sf.query(@"SELECT Id, Name, Username FROM User WHERE Username='" + NewOwner + "'");
    List<SFDC.User> tmpName = sfSoap.ConvertToList<SFDC.User>(q1);
    Logger.getInstance().LogMessage("Found '" + NewOwner + "', id='" + tmpName[0].Id + "'");
    sfcase.OwnerId = tmpName[0].Id;

    SFDC.sObject[] toUpdate = new SFDC.sObject[1];
    toUpdate[0] = sfcase;
    sf.update(toUpdate);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logger.getInstance().LogMessage("AssignTo Error: " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
  }
}
```

Some notes:

- The SalesForce data types from the WSDL are in the SFDC namespace, e.g. `SFDC.Case` refers to a SalesForce `Case` object.
- I can confirm that the query inside the `try` block is executing successfully and returning a valid object.
- The sfSoap object is a simple wrapper around the SoapClient object.

I'm guessing that I'm not setting the `OwnerId` property to the right value, but you can't query `Name` objects so I'm not sure what precisely to do.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Can you post the endpoint this is going to? Are you using the Partner or Enterprise API?

Comment: It's the Enterprise API.

Comment: Please post your endpoint.

Comment: You might try changing the type for the update to SFDC.Case instead of SFDC.sObject, based on the error message it sounds like it wants a specific sObject instead of the generic one ...

Comment: No-go, @Ralph.

Here is the endpoint config:

`<client><endpoint address="https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/27.0/0DFU0000000L60i" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding" contract="SFDC.Soap" name="Soap" /></client>`

Comment: Endpoint is correct for the Enterprise wsdl.  My next thought was what Ralph suggested . i.e to use the specific object type but looks like that's not helping either.

Comment: I don't use the Enterprise wsdl much. But maybe change `toUpdate` to be a `SFDC.Case[]`. Failing that, check that sfCase has the type defined when it is cast to an sObject.

Comment: Well, I did confirm that the OwnerId field for the cases I own matches the Id of the User object my query is returning.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue.

The problem was, apparently, that the update() call really doesn't like it when you have a lot of data included in the object. Probably, something I was retrieving was not update()able.

So, the solution: create an empty object where only the object's `Id` and the fields that actually need to be updated (in my case, `OwnerId`) are set, and send that object to the update() call.

```
var tmp = new SFDC.Case();
tmp.Id = sfcase.Id;
tmp.OwnerId = tmpName[0].Id;
sf.update( new SFDC.Case[] { tmp } );
```

Comment: I see that you are also using an array of SFDC.Case rather than SFDC.sObject.

Comment: Glad you solved it.

Comment: Good approach, shame the error messages can be such a red herring trying to resolve this ...